# "Faster" version of powers.

Tags: arithmetic

I know that essentially, multiplication is just a faster version of addition, as $5 \times 3$ is just $5 + 5 + 5$. I also know that powers are a faster version of multiplication as $5^3$ is $5 \times 5 \times 5$. I am wondering if there is a faster version of powers such as $5$ insert symbol $3$ is $5^{(5^5)}$.

Comment: Is it https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration you are looking for?

Comment: Some write this as ${}^3 5$, but there are other notations as well.

Comment: You also might want to check out [Knuth's up arrow notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_up-arrow_notation).

Answer (score 1):

The operation you describe is called [tetration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration) and is sometimes denoted with a leading superscript.  For instance,
$$  {}^3 5 = 5^{5^5}  \text{.}  $$
More generally, for real $a \neq 0$ and nonnegative integer $n$,
$$    {}^n a = \begin{cases}
    1 ,& n = 0  \\
    a^{\left( {}^{(n-1)} a \right)}   ,& n > 0  \text{.}
\end{cases}  $$

The generalization you are starting along is the [hyperoperation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperoperation) sequence.  Continuing on, each operation is just repeated application of the previous operation.  Tetration is repeated exponentiation, [pentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentation) is repeated tetration, and so on.  (The notation for hyperoperations is ... awful, but they don't usually come up, so there is little need to make it better.)

Comment: Wow, I didn't know about hyperoperations! So awesome!